# Toggle eraser by tapping or holding pen button

Tags: gimp, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos (non-Pro). The pen has no eraser on the rear end. I’d like to set it up so I can press or hold one of the thumb buttons on the pen or a key on the keyboard to toggle between the paintbrush and eraser. I have only found key modifiers that let you switch directly to one tool or another, but then I have to keep moving between keys/buttons to toggle. I’d like to keep it simpler than that. Is there a way to set this up?

I’m on Windows 11.

Comment: Different strokes :) Decades using a Wacom that *does* have an eraser end and I've never used it, not once.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, hardware questions are generally off topic here. But any configuration of the buttons would likely need to be done in the Wacom preferences, and would have little to do with GIMP.

Comment: Also, it may be possible to just switch tools in GIMP using the shortcuts "Shift+E" for the Eraser, "P" for the Paint tool, or you could customize the shortcuts in GIMP.

Comment: @Scott, I used one years ago that had an eraser, but I quickly stopped using it because it's so inconvenient to flip it around. I'm trying to find a way to swap between paintbrush and eraser quickly, which would be helpful even if I did have an eraser end. Do you have any recommendations for setting it up?

Comment: @BillyKerr Isn't this primarily a Gimp software question? If I could set up a toggle in Gimp, I could easily map it to whatever I wanted in the Wacom settings. I currently have two buttons set up, one for the Paintbrush shortcut, and one for the Eraser shortcut. What I'm trying to find is a way to use a single shortcut in Gimp to toggle between them. I mention my Wacom without eraser so no one suggests I just use the eraser end.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - as far as I know, GIMP doesn't have a way to toggle between the eraser and paint tools with one key.

Comment: I've never touched Gimp.. so no it's not a Gimp question. it's a Wacom (hardware) question. If I HAD to.. I'd *perhaps* set the side buttons - bottom B, and top E for Photoshop specifically. Then you could use the buttons to toggle between the brush and the eraser. Honestly, I just tap E on the keyboard if I need the eraser. As far as I know, there's no Wacom ability to toggle any app setting. It *always* takes 2 settings for toggle-like behavior.

Comment: I don't know about Gimp.. but with Photoshop you can customize tool shortcuts. In Photoshop, if you set a shortcut to the the same keystroke for multiple tools, the Shift key walks through the list. Example, set Eraser shortcut to F and set the Brush shortcut to F. Then Shift-F will select whatever is next (not in use). Shift-F essentially becomes a toggle.

Comment: Can you use the brush in `Erase` mode instead of using the eraser? In which case it's a SMOP to write a script that toggles between the `Normal` and `Erase` modes, and assign it to a shortcut.

Comment: It *is* a Gimp software question because that’s how I tagged it and I’m the one asking. I can set a toggle button for the eraser in Krita. This can then easily be set to any button on a Wacom. I’m asking if it can be done in Gimp.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - I am a GIMP user, and have bee for many years, and as far as I know there's no way to set up a toggle for the paint/erase tools.  There is no such functionality.  Of course you could request it as a feature. Maybe other people would find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, @BillyKerr. Based on your experience, that's a good enough answer for me if you want to post it.